# Can someone please tell me why the void function isn't working? And why does it stop at the main function and not complete the rest?

Tags: c

what is the problem with the code?
When the code runs it only execute the first part of the code only, ignoring the void functions.
What did I do wrong and what's missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void Fun2_xxx_F3();
void F3();
int main()
{
int Function1_60897_F3,M,A=6,B=8,items=1,counter=0,d; //decleration
float price,discount,discounta,total_discount;
  
   
printf("Function1_xxx_F3 is created by student ID = xxx- section F3"); //print student name and id

  if (A>B) //decide the value of M
  {
   M=A;
  }
  else if(A<B)
  {
   M=B;
  }

  while(items<=M)//Calculate the sum of 10% discount items
  {
   printf("\n\nEnter the price of item %d: ",items);
   scanf("%f",&price);
   
  if(price<1100)
   {
   discounta=price-price*10/100;
   printf("\nThe price of the item after discount = %.3f KD",discounta);
   total_discount+=discounta;
   counter++;
   }
      
  if(price>=1100 && price<=2200)
  {
   discount=price-price*15/100;
   printf("\nThe price of the item after discount = %.3f KD",discount);
  }
      
  if(price>2200)
  {
   discount=price-price*20/100;
   printf("\nThe price of the item after discount = %.3f KD",discount);
  }
   
items++;
}
printf("\n\nThe total price after discount of all items that got a discount of 10 percent is: %.3f KD",total_discount);
  

void Fun2_xxx_F3() //define void function
{
int M;
unsigned int computer=1,counter=0,counter2=0;                              //decleration 
float computer_price,computer_tax,avg1,avg2,computer_tax3=0,computer_tax5=0;
M=30;
char S1[60897]= "XXX YYY section:F3 ID xxx";// define a local string variable named S1 with size equal to 60897

printf("M is equal to the sum of my ID-number:xxx which is: %d",M);
printf("\n\nFunction (Fun2_xxx_F3) is created by student: %s\n\n\n",S1);

  while(computer<=30) //calculate the average price of all computers with and without tax.
  {
   printf("\nEnter the price of 30 computers: ");
   scanf("%f",&computer_price);


  if (computer_price> 1100)
  {
   computer_tax= computer_price+computer_price*3/100;
   computer_tax3+=computer_tax;
   counter++;
  }
  else if(computer_price<= 1100)
  {
   computer_tax= computer_price+computer_price*5/100;
   computer_tax5+=computer_tax;
   counter2++;
  }
   computer++;
  }
  
avg1=computer_tax3/counter; //calculate the average price after tax of all computers which get a tax of 3% 
avg2=(computer_tax3+computer_tax5)/30;
printf("\n\n%.3f KD ... %.3f KD",avg1, avg2);
}

void F3() //void function 2
{
int i=6;
unsigned int N;
  for(N=1 ; N<=i ; N+=1)//print on the screen your ID, your name and your section i
times
  {
   printf("ID:xxx   Name:XXX YYY   SECTION:F3");
  }

}
}
```

Also what is meant by:
Write a main function based on the following:
• No local variables in the body of the main function.
• Call the first function Function1_42357_F2 with the value of your ID for the actual parameters.
• Call the functions Fun2 and F3

Comment: I'm sorry the posted code won't compile, so it can't run. But I notice that functions `void Fun2_xxx_F3()`  and `void F3()` don't seem to get called at all. Functions do not run automatically, they must be called from another function.

Comment: The first of the three task instructions says not to define local variables inside `main()`, but your `main()` begins by doing just that. Those variables must be global to conform (but whether that is good policy is arguable).

Comment: Aside: please do not post links to external details of the problem (especially when the link is to your own computer). Try to make the question self contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand how a function works in C programming language.
In this case a main function can be written as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int    main(void)
{
    Function1_42357_F2(your_id_here);    
    Fun2_xxx_F3();
    F3();
    return (0);
}
```

You need to adjust the code accordingly to make it work.